# JQuery Textfield change event not fired

Tags: jquery, events, onchange

I have **Account ID(Select),Account Name, Percentage(Text) and Total columns** in the JQuery Table. Whenever the account id select changes, the corresponding Account Name will be placed in the nearby **Account Name** column. Once the percentage is entered and focus changes, the **Total column** wil get its value by some calculation. Below are the code declarations and event bindings. Select change event fires properly and **Account Name** is rendered in the table but the **Percentage column** is not firing the change event. Where i am going wrong?

***Account ID declaration***

```
                        <TD>
                        <div id='emptySubAcc' >
                                <select class='subAccHolder subAcc' id='subAccID' name='subAccName' >
                                <option value=''></option>
                                <option value='subaccount1'>subaccount1</option>
                                <option value='subaccount2'>subaccount2</option>
                                <option value='subaccount3'>subaccount3</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </TD>

//    Event binding
    $("#allocTable tbody").delegate(".subAccHolder","change",function() {
    // Setting the account Name
    }
```

***Percentage Declaration***

```
 <input type="text" id="percentID' class='percentHolder' name='percentName' value="">

    //Event Binding
                $("#allocTable tbody").delegate(".percentHolder","change",function() {
                    alert('Text value changed');
                });
```

Comment: Have you wrap it with document ready event?

Comment: Yes, both the event binding are in document ready event. In fact Account ID (Select) event fires...

Comment: your <input> has a quote mistake in the example above, id attribute is opened with a double quote and closed with a single quote.

Comment: could you show your `Account ID(Select),Account Name, Percentage(Text) and Total columns` html elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your issue:

```
 <input type="text" id="percentID' class='percentHolder' name='percentName' value="">
```

notice you start with " quote and close with ' quote ?

even SO syntax highlighting sees it ;)

Answer (score 0):

For:

```
$("#allocTable tbody").delegate(".subAccHolder","change",function() { 
// Setting the account Name 
}
```

Use:

```
$("#<selectid>").change(function(){
//your stuff here
});
```

Comment: better coding, but shouldn't matter

Comment: not really better coding.. he probably delegated that event for a reason, such as dynamically changing the table body

Comment: yes, you are right.I delegated the events because my rows will change dynamically.